# objective-c nsbundle

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsbundle

I am developing an iOS app using iOS 4.3 SDK, but I want the app to change the icon name on the iPad screen dynamically every time I closed the app.

According to my knowledge, I can do this using NSBundle but I don't know how can I acheive this. Can anybody suggest me ? 
can someone post the sample piece of code ?

More Details: I have a form where I input data and insert into sqllite db. I want to display the icon name like below every time I save data into sqllite db.

**"My Application 2 records exists"**  if I saved 2 records.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot change your application display name! It is read from your (code-signed!) .plist (or one of your localized Info-Plist.strings).

If you want to inform the user of the nuber of records you should consider using badge numbers: `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:2]`

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. 
On which app event I can write this code so that every time I close the app, it will be updated.

Comment: you should update the value whenever your data representing this state updates (so if the user kills your app, the number is already set). alternatively you can implement `applicationDidEnterBackground` or `applicationWillTerminate` but this is really if you have no other possibility!